# Windows SBS 2008 - Applying user restrictions

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

I have a SBS2008 server and I need to restrict program access on a per group basis, see below for the view from Active Directory.

How do I go about restricting the User's in the group "Advisors With Restrictions". I need to stop them from opening certain programs (Word, Excel, Internet Explorer, RegEdit, Control Panel etc etc)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can manage this through Group Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811966.aspx)

```
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Run only allowed Windows applications
```

Comment: thanks for this - I've found that but, how do I make this specific to a group like above?

Comment: In the Group Policy Management Console. If you already have the policy setup, right click on that OU container and choose "Link an Existing GPO...", then choose it. If you don't have it created, right click on the OU and choose "Create a GPO in this domain, and Link it here..."